# condition execution in upstart conf ok to do?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have a app-update service that does the sync to server with its conf as :

```
start on started engine
stop on stopped engine or firmware_update_mode
```

Now, i get wifi status on the device at `/var/run/engine/wifi` with status up/down. I'm now trying to understand what would be the right way to let this app-update service run only on up wifi and stop it on down wifi. Ofcourse, it will only run when the engine running as well. Hence, it should run as a condition execution i.e.

start on engine **and** wifi up, stop on wifi down.

Is app-update.conf the right place to put such condition execution (run on wifi up, stop on wifi down)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another job:

```
start on file EVENT=modify FILE=/var/run/engine/wifi or starting app-update

task

script
    if grep -q "^up" /var/run/engine/wifi && \
       initctl status engine | grep -q "start/running"
    then
        start app-update
    elif grep -q "^down" /var/run/engine/wifi; then
        stop app-update
    fi
end script
```

This will check to see if the wifi is up when app-update first starts, and will start and stop app-update when the wifi goes up or down.

This is a little complicated, unfortunately, since Upstart does not have state support (only events).

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, it worked when there was a wifi up but then it terminated. one reason could be that i don't have inotify-upstart file bridge verison (running old ubuntu). but i do have inotify itself. hence i'm now chehcking for  the file, if it exists. Not sure, but is the pre-start a right place for such chehcking? `pre-start script
  # Wait for the wifi file to appear.
  FILE=/var/run/engine/wifistatus
  while [ ! -e $FILE ] ; do
    inotifywait -t 2 -e create $(dirname $FILE)
  done
end script `

Comment: i did try your solution with this : http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-when-a-file-or-directory-is-created-deleted but since upstart is old, i think it terminates because file line is exits (no file bridge support here.). Is there a better way to chehck for a file and then try your solution? may be in pre-start or another job?

Comment: since i ahve upstart without file bridge, i let another script chehck for wifi file using inotify and let that start update job. here are the two update jobs and one script on paste link: http://pastebin.com/mYHhr5V8 . Problem is wifi job shows as "the job is terminated". but when i run the wifi_script, it works fine in blocking mode as it keeps looking at the directory using inotifywait. why would upstart terminate a while look on inotifywait? looks like i'm doing something wrong.